# Creating a new folder into another new folder

Tags: java, file, mkdir

I know how to create a new folder, but i don't know how to way to create an another new folder into a new folder i just created

```
String y="C:/TEMP/Four Area";
File file=new File(y);
if(file.mkdir()){
    System.out.println("file is created");
}else{
    System.out.println("file is created");
}
```

But what i want is "C://TEMP/Four Area/New Area", i want system to create "New Area" folder into "Four Area" folder in above code.
I tried to use `String y="C://TEMP/Four Area/New Area`, it won't create any folder

Comment: Sorry, wrong typing. I was typing the code by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`file.mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) instead to create multiple nested directories

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any
>   necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this
>   operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the
>   necessary parent directories.